# Facing issues while trying to set Upload Limits settings in Page level

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have upload functionality in my application. I was facing an upload issue and found out that in Web.Config there is `httpRuntime` tag. I set the change as below.

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
```

This fixed my upload issue. The above is my Web.Config in my root folder, one that we get by default.

Questions.

1. Can I create a seperate Web.config file? If Yes, I have to upload the files in some other Virtual Directory and my code is in some other project. So where shall i place the Web.Config file ?
2. Is it possible to set these settings at page level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a web.config file to nearly any folder (I *doubt* the app_data would allow it (but I could be wrong, however this is beside the point)).

You can of course (if possible) create many folders for each setting you need. In other words, have 1 file per folder to get around your issue.

Or, create a new parent folder which you want all sub folders to 'inherit' your new web.config file from. Your web.config file goes into this new parent folder.

Remember, the web.config file inherits from the parent web.config file, so you don't need to write the entire configuration again, just the section you want to add/overwrite.